# Creating a vanilla instance from a site already set up

Tags: nodes

I have a Drupal site which is set up, running and being continuously used.  It has a variety of content_types, taxonomies and field_collections etc saved in the database.  The plan is to sell on vanilla instances of this Drupal site - which means, clearing out all the content and resetting all table indexes to 1 etc.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy options:

- Use the Delete All Module and it's Drush interface.
- If that's not thorough enough, I typically just end up using an `SQL` script to set foreign key checks to 0; and then truncate all fields, cache, revision, users, user_roles ... etc tables specific to my site. While it seems like alot of work it's basically a 1 time audit of the underlying DB for the script creation and simply tracking what new tables are needed for wiping when you add new modules. I've then used Rules_Link and the `php filter` to make this SQL statements runnable via a button press from a displaysuite panel ...